# ASP.NET Identity properties extension

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am using Asp.Net Identity for authentication and my requirement is after login currently I can access only **User.Identity.Name** which is username only.

Is there any way I can add more properties after login like

```
User.Identity.UserType
User.Identity.DepartmentId
```

Reason why I wanna use this to avoid Session to identify the user on Views.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need add custom claim to user. For exmaple after creating user:

```
await _userManager.Value.AddClaimAsync(user, new Claim("UserType", "SomeType"));
```

Then create an extension method to read claim value:

```
public static string GetUserType(this IIdentity identity)
{
    if (identity == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(identity));

    var claim = ((ClaimsIdentity)identity).FindFirst("UserType")?.Value;

    return claim ?? string.Empty;
}
```

And you after login you can access user type:

```
var userType = User.Identity.GetUserType();
```

And here is a generic extension to get custom claim:

```
public static T Get<T>(this IIdentity identity, string propertyName)
{
    if (identity == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(identity));

    var value = ((ClaimsIdentity)identity).FindFirst(propertyName)?.Value;
    if (value == null)
        return default(T);

    var type = typeof(T);
    if (type.IsEnum)
        return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value);

    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
}
```

For example, you have an enum for `UserType`:

```
public enum UserType 
{
    Admin,
    Editor,
    User,
}

var userType = User.Identity.Get<UserType>("UserType");
var representativeId = User.Identity.Get<int>("DepartmentId");
```